# Limiting socket server access

Tags: php, security, sockets

This is security issue. I've got a socket server that should be accessed only from the same server, in other words, only from **localhost**. I need to somehow check if remote user that trying to connect is not an outsider. Currently I've come up with:

```
socket_getpeername($current_socket, $client_address, $client_port);

if( $client_address == '127.0.0.1' )
{
   //allow
}
```

But such approach is not the best one, because I need to `socket_accept()` *any* user before proceeding. Does anybody know how to handle it?

Comment: What about firewalling the port? Set a rule to prevent external access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepting the socket and then dropping the connection is totally acceptable.

If you don't like it, you can set up a firewall rule in your OS to allow connections only from localhost.

Comment: Yes, I thought something like this... Will trust your experience and reputation. Thank you! : )

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you make your socket listen only to 127.0.0.1. This way it's only connectable from localhost.

I assume you are using [stream_socket_server()](http://php.net/stream_socket_server)

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("udp://127.0.0.1:1113", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND);
if (!$socket) {
    die("$errstr ($errno)");
}
```

Comment: No, I'm using `socket_create()` with `SOCK_STREAM` and then `socket_bind()` to `localhost` - this is for the server; however, even then someone is able to connect to 127.0.0.1 via, say, telnet. I'm also using my own authentication system, but, theoretically, it can be bypassed. My client, that listens to server, is secured, but somebody might just replicate client script and connect to server, that was my main concern.

Comment: @grimv01k But if they connect to your server from localhost using telnet, the client address would still be 127.0.0.1. So if your socket only listens for connections on localhost, all connections will come from localhost. And your check would be redundant.